# Viber No Connection on Ubuntu 22.04 even I have an internet

Tags: viber, 22.04

I really want to use the latest Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, BUT when i tried to install the Viber, The viber won't work and it says "No Connection" even I have an internet connection:

[image: Viber No Connection ScreenShot]

Hope anyone can help. thank you!

I install this: https://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb

Comment: Looking at the [supported platforms](https://help.viber.com/en/article/supported-platforms) notes, it looks like the installation file may be targeted to work with specific libraries. Are there any error messages in `/var/log/syslog` (or elsewhere in `/var/log`) that might point to the issue?

Comment: Hi @matigo Thank you so much for your response here. I really appreciate it.

I checked the supported platforms, and it seems that my system is supported "Linux Fedora and Ubuntu (64 bit)" I'm using 64bit.

While checking the `/var/log/syslog` and doing `tail -f /var/log/syslog` while opening the Viber app, there is no logs on syslog

mmmh.. what specific logs name do you mean on elsewhere in `/var/log` ?

Comment: You can copy the libraries from `libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb` inside /opt/viber/lib and you're set.

Comment: answer based on @GeorgeLitos comment https://askubuntu.com/a/1409882/652604

Comment: Viber is always broken for Linux, always late on the dependencies. Maybe submitting a ticket would help? Go here and answer "No" to "Did this answer your question?", then submit a ticket asking them to update Viber to libssl3 on Ubuntu 22.04: https://help.viber.com/en/article/supported-platforms

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ubuntu moved to libssl3 with 22.04, as libssl1.1 has been deprecated. You have to get libssl1.1 from 21.10 and make Viber work with it. Here are instructions:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb

sudo nano /usr/share/applications/viber.desktop
```

Then change the `Exec` line to:

```
Exec=LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so /opt/viber/Viber %u
```

Comment: Hi Filip, Thank you so much for your help. This solved my problem.

Cheers!

Comment: Just remove the %u from the command line after installing the package
Exec=/opt/viber/Viber

Comment: Thank you very much. That saved my day! :D

Comment: Installing packages from other Ubuntu versions is a bad idea. This is a good way to get baffling system breakage sometime later.

Comment: `libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb` is no longer aviliable so you have to change both commands like `wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb` and `sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb`

Comment: ilibssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb s no longer available, download libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb from here https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/amd64/libssl1.1/download instead.

Comment: Far from an ideal solution, as 20.10 repositories are no longer available, and those packages are never updated.

Answer (score 7):

### How to install Viber in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS properly

#### (updated 11.01.23)

#### 1. Optional Download Viber or skip if you already have `viber.AppImage`

```bash
wget -P ~/Downloads https://download.cdn.viber.com/desktop/Linux/viber.AppImage
```

#### 2. Extract from AppImage & move to `/opt`

```bash
chmod +x ~/Downloads/viber.AppImage
~/Downloads/viber.AppImage --appimage-extract
sudo mv ~/squashfs-root /opt/viber
```

#### 3. Download working libs & replace broken ones in `/opt/viber/lib`

```bash
export libsfilename="libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb"
wget -P ~/Downloads http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/$libsfilename
dpkg -x ~/Downloads/$libsfilename ~/Downloads/viberlibs/
sudo rm /opt/viber/lib/libssl.so.* /opt/viber/lib/libcrypto.so.*
sudo cp ~/Downloads/viberlibs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib* /opt/viber/lib/
rm ~/Downloads/$libsfilename
```

#### 4. Move launcher to application folder & edit `viber.desktop` (point to actual `Viber` executable)

```bash
sudo cp /opt/viber/viber.desktop /usr/share/applications
sudo sed -i "s/Exec=.*/Exec=\/opt\/viber\/Viber/" /usr/share/applications/viber.desktop
sudo sed -i "s/Icon.*/Icon=\/opt\/viber\/viber\.png/" /usr/share/applications/viber.desktop
```

#### Profit! Open your launcher and there should be working `Viber` (if not logout & login)

Comment: I think that's a great workaround. Couple of mistakes though:

1) viber.appimage needs to get permission as an executable to extract
2) Correct move line is `sudo mv ~/squashfs-root /opt/viber` (not ~/Downloads/squash-root)
3) rm -rf line needs root permissions (`sudo rm -rf ~/Downloads/viberlibs/`)
4) Step 4 doesn't work, I logged out and back in, no Viber in the launcher. I bet we can fix that. 
Nonetheless, it works great from its original location (`/opt/viber/Viber`)

Comment: There's something wrong with last step (sed -i). I tried to change it, but it's not my thing... All it does is that it changes the line to point to the correct executable location, right? Still, Viber app doesn't show up in launcher, don't know why

Comment: Sorry @madzzohan, my bad! Only problem was the icon link :D
Fixed it (Exec=/opt/viber/Viber and
Icon=/opt/viber/viber.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136510/discussion-between-giorgos-tph-and-madzohan).

Answer (score 5):

The following sequence of commands worked for me to install a working viber client in a new Ubuntu 22.04 installation:

```
wget https://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb
sudo apt install ./viber.deb
rm -rf viber.deb

# install the old, yet compatible with viber, openssl libs,
# to remove the "No connection" error at client startup
DEV=libssl-dev_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
NON_DEV=libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/$DEV
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/$NON_DEV
sudo apt install ./$DEV ./$NON_DEV
rm -rf $DEV $NON_DEV
```

Now it should be ready to go!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved by installing the following packages libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb, libssl-dev_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb

Answer (score 1):

I installed it using flatpak:

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub com.viber.Viber
echo "flatpak run com.viber.Viber" | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/viber
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/viber
```

Start viber with:

```
viber
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up previous comments, case is closed.

I went with [madzohan's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1409882/139824) for a while, but Viber's current version (18.2.0.2) seems to have solved the issue (and some others, too).

So, all you need to do is download [latest Viber version](https://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb) and install.