# Viber closes after launch

Tags: viber

Ubuntu 20.04 - Viber closes after launch, for 3-5 seconds there is an empty frame from the viber window, after that it just closes without messages. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling didn't help. Started 3-5 days ago. Before that it worked well. Ubuntu 20.04 has been fully updated for today.

Comment: I don't know the app (and an `apt-cache search` didn't show anything) so did you search logs for messages?  Any crash file in `/var/crash`, or if it's a snap (I did find a result with `snap search`) did you try running it from terminal with logging to see if you got clues?  (`--enable-logging=stderr --v=1` etc)

Comment: Yes, in this folder there is a file specifically for viber, but I can’t understand its contents. https://fex.net/ru/s/xt12aao

Comment: This will help as WA when using X11: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427367/viber-doesnt-start-under-x11. Basically, you change keyboard layout to other than english, start Viber, then switch back to english.

Answer (score -1):

Did not help any advice on any sites. In the new version of Ubuntu 22.04, the Viber does not work either. Where it works: in version of Kubuntu 22.04 and two tips related to installing the encryption library.

Ubuntu broke libssl compatibility with 22.04. You have to get libssl 1.2.1 from 21.10 and make Viber work with it. Here are instructions to fix this:
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb

sudo nano /usr/share/applications/viber.desktop

Then change the Exec line to:
Exec=LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so /opt/viber/Viber %u
here you need to remove the "%u" sign after Viber

[Viber No Connection on Ubuntu 22.04 even I have an internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403319/viber-no-connection-on-ubuntu-22-04-even-i-have-an-internet)