# Viber no internet connection on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, lenovo, windows-subsystem-for-linux, viber

I installed the Viber application on my Lenovo x1 carbon 3rd gen laptop. But when I opened the Viber application, there was a "no internet connection warning" message showing me. Please give me any suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Viber No Connection on Ubuntu 22.04 even I have an internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403319/viber-no-connection-on-ubuntu-22-04-even-i-have-an-internet)

Comment: To help answer the question, it may be helpful to have the following data: What version and flavour of Ubuntu are you using (e.g., Ubuntu 20.04, Kubuntu 22.04, or something like that). How are you installing Viber? And is there anything special about your Internet setup (like a proxy or VPN)?